# Can Socat be used as a stand alone HTTP proxy

Tags: networking

I have heard that Socat can be used to proxy HTTP requests.

I recently attempted to set up Socat to do such a thing, with the hope of using it as a very simple standalone (i.e. being able to proxy with socat without the use of Squid for instance) HTTP proxy however upon examining the man page and scouring the web it seems that you can only forward to an existing proxy server. That is, it seems that Socat is incapable of receiving a HTTP proxy request and then connecting to the HTTP host specified in the request.

Is this the case or am I missing something here?